# rename files in sub directories

Tags: for-loop, rename, filenames, mv

I am running the fallowing script to rename files numerical with in all sub directories and sub directories.

```
num=1   
echo "Enter the file path"
read -r path 
cd $path 
for file in $path/*.tif; do
       mv -v "${file}" "$path/$(printf "%04d" ${num}).tif"
       num=$(( ${num} + 1 ))
done
```

when I run the script it only runs on the root dir and not the sub directories as well?
What can I add or is there a different way to write the script?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
num=1   
echo "Enter the file path"
read -r path 
shopt -s globstar # enable recursion **
cd "$path" 
for file in $path/**/*.tif; do
       mv -v "$file" "$path/$(printf "%04d" $num.tif)"
       ((num++))
done
```

Or using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's/.*/sprintf "%04d%s", ++$::c, ".tif"/e' ./$path/**/*.tif
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

Comment: I was looking to run my command with out using the renamer library.

Comment: I gave you 2 solutions

Comment: When I run the above script I get the fallowing error

The script with this

read -r path 
shopt -s globstar # enable recursion **
cd "$path" 
for file in $path/**/*.tif; do

This is the error I get

~/Desktop/test2.sh: line 6: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
~/Desktop/test2.sh: line 9: printf: 1.tif: invalid number

Comment: Use `bash` as shell. Which one do you use?

Comment: I use version 3.2.57

Comment: Which OS? Looks very outdated: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156808/12574

Comment: I am running it on Mac

Comment: I found this code to work. It uses nested for loops. Is there another way to do it
for d in $(find . -type d); 
do 
num=1
   for file in $(find "$d" -depth 1 -name '*.tif' | sort -n )
  do 
    printf -v newf "%04d" $((num++))
    mv $file $d/$newf.tif 
  done
done

Comment: You can use this code in `zsh` (remove `shopt -s globstar`)

Comment: I am trying to do it with out installing renamer

Comment: I talk about `zsh` shell. Simple type `zsh` in your terminal, then `enter`, then paste the whole code without `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: Did you figured out the way to ru the code in zsh?

Comment: I am still looking for simple way to write the cmmand with out using renamer

Comment: You have MacOS true? So you have `zsh` installed. I told you to run the code in `zsh` instead of `bash`